# Визуализация сортировки выбором

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    int minValueIndex = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Count; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[minValueIndex])
        {
            minValueIndex = j;
        }
    }
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[minValueIndex];
    array[minValueIndex] = temp;

    chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(null, array);
}
```

Код почему-то виснет и только через секунд 10 строит уже отсортированный график, то бишь промежуточных построений не видно. Из-за чего это может быть?

Догадываюсь, что влияет `Thread.Sleep()`, но как обойтись без него не знаю, ибо необходимо пошагово [*с интервалами между прорисовками*] показать сортировку...

Comment: Так делать нельзя. Нужно или цикл с ProcessMessages (как в c# звучит не знаю) или ставить таймер, и раз в секунду отправлять разный array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ты в основном потоке делаешь остановку на полсекунды (Thread.Sleep), т.е он сначала считает, заносит в chart, при этом поток формы останалвивается на сортировке (не обновляется окно и т.д.) после этого обновляет форму, попробуй сразу после занесения значения в chart вызвать refresh() для него.

Comment: Действительно, достаточно было добавить chart1.Update(); после отрисовки и сразу стало видно результат. Большое спасибо за ответ!